# Python No module Error with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run some python 3.4 example on visual studio 2013. when I try to `import` some module from a parent folder and run it from inside visual studio 2013, I always has the error of `ImportError: No module named 'foo'`

However, when I run it from the console using the python command `python boo.py`, it executes well.

As an example, this is my project structure

```
myproject/
  foo.py
  __init__.py
  koo/
    boo.py
    __init__.py
```

`foo.py` content is

```
def do1():
  print('Inside foo module')
```

`boo.py` content is

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
import foo

foo.do1()
```

Comment: When you run it from VS, the current directory isn't `myproject/koo`, so adding `..` isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Try using `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '\\..')` instead.

Comment: @martineau .. This one worked .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this issue is not about Visual Studio and not about why it doesn't work in VS. The real question is why it works in the terminal. Probably it is because the terminal runs under different environmental settings, where the python interpreter can find the parent directory and thus the foo.py:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:

- the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
- PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the
  shell variable PATH).
- the installation-dependent default.

> After initialization, Python programs can modify sys.path. The
>   directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning
>   of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means
>   that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of
>   the same name in the library directory. This is an error unless the
>   replacement is intended. See section Standard Modules for more
>   information.

So, add the parent dir to pythonpath, and it will work.
Or modify sys.path adding the parent dir to it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion .. But I am mainly interested to know why it does not work in VS2013 .. Also I don't want to make it PYTHONPATH dependent

Comment: Then simply move foo.py to child directory

Comment: Moving the file to the child directory is not a solution .. as this means that I will not be able to organize future projects in VS environment.

Comment: Also as I said, I don't want to make it dependent on PYTHONPATH

Comment: Anyway .. Thanks for the investigation you made.

Comment: OK, OK but what about modifying sys.path from script adding the parent dir to it? Or you search some VD specific solution. Then you will depend on VS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me:

```
import sys
 sys.path.append("Folder PATH"). "Folder PATH" given as...C:\\Working_directory\\VSProject
import <MODULE_NAME>
```